# Order Statistic Red Black Binary Tree in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

Are there python libraries for implemented order statistic Red Black Binary tree? I have not been able to find any so far.

Problem that I am trying to solve :

Given a sequence : 1,2,3,4,1,4,2,3 : Labels -> 1,2,3,4

Call first occurrence of a label i  as L_i and second occurrence of label i as U_i

I want to count number of j's such that index(L_i) < index(L_j) but index(U_i) < index(U_j) for all i

```
Input : 1,2,3,4,1,4,2,3 
Output :  4
```

because |j| = 3 because index(L_1) < index(L_{2,3,4}) and index(U_1)

This can be done in `theta(n^2)` by linear search in array for every point but using balanced order statistic RBTree can help in accomplishing this in `theta(n*log(n))`.

This is my thinking:

```
for each label in sequence:
 count= count + search(label)
```

While searching, if you can not find the label then insert it and return 0 : O(logn)

While searching, if you found the label then delete it and count number of nodes greater than that and return that number